# flutter: how to create a directory in my file

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a directory in flutter. for creating a directory or folder I need to path and directory name. by using path provider we can create a directory in application folder. but I want to create a directory that easily accessible for user like in download folder, document folder or in root of my file. how can i achieve that please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `'${await getDownloadsDirectory()}/<PATH YOU WANT>'`.

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/path_provider/path_provider/lib/path_provider.dart#L215